# ESP32 on custom board power problem

Tags: power-supply, pcb-design, voltage-regulator, esp32

I have an ESP32 controlling 8 relays.

When I power up it works as expected but if I try to activate more than 3 relays it resets, sometimes it has problems connecting to the WIFI, reseting itself.

I think is a power related problem.

Here is my current schematic:

[image]

I think D3 and D4 are generating a substantial voltage drop. I think I could solve it with the following changes:

- Replacing D2 and D4 (B5819W) with a single 1N5819
- Adding two 220uF capacitors on the input and output of the voltage regulator

[image]

1. Is the 1N5819 a good selection for this application?
2. Is it a good idea to place the two capacitors?  Are the values reasonable?

Edit: Included layout picture.

Top Layer : GND
Bottom Layer (relay section) : VIN

[image]

Comment: "Replacing D2 and D4" <- there is no D2 in your schematic, and D4 is a LED. Are you referring to D3 & D7?

Comment: Yes sorry,  D2 and D7

Comment: if you have a bunch of out caps on your vreg, consider capping the esp's reset pin too to delay bootup until 3.3v stabilizes.

Comment: What relays those are? How much does one relay consume current?

Comment: _”I think D3 and D4 are generating a substantial voltage drop”_ Don’t. Measure it. How does 3.3 V look on your scope during relay switching?

Answer (score 1):

I also think it’s power related; on a certain level the esp will trigger its brownout detector. And like already mentioned EMI problems could also be tricking.

Do you really need the Vbus power for your power supply? You could disconnect Vbus from the general supply and only connect to the CP2102. That’s already a diode / voltagedrop lesser.

Design powertraces at least 20 mils or more wide, the feeding trace to the ESP is long and takes a fair amount of current. Signals 6 mils wide and to the relays keep them at least 12 mils out of each other. (Crosstalk/emi). Also some capacitors seem to far away, like C10 (compared to the via).

If I look at the datasheets of the bjt’s at the relays, I wonder if the base current is not too small. (Hfe, see datasheet) Especially if multiple relays are activated.

Is your GND (or better said return path, ) consistent? At the left side it seems to be almost broken by the gpio’s. At the right divided by the signal traces to the relays. Maybe consider gnd bridges on the power poly.

Comment: I think is power related because you can turn on 3 relays without problem, they can be any of them 1-8, but when the fourth one (sometimes) or fifth (always) is energized the ESP32 reboots, I would like to have the VBUS as is very handy during coding as I don't have to use an external power supply as it's powered by the USB.

Comment: Maybe consider gnd bridges on the power poly <= could you please clarify this. do you mean use the top layer as a continous GND plane?

Comment: In high speed design, the return path tends to stick to the feeding route, but in this case it will use the shortest route possible. Even when there is no obvious route. It can lead to ground bounce. Maybe it’s easier to make the second layer GND, a good return path is key, and design the power poly’s on the first with the signals. Ground next to signals in the same plane has almost no value. Here it’s pretty much the distance to help.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the 1N5819 a good selection for this application?

If cost isn't an issue you should consider a fet solution (they make power sharing IC's) (there are also plenty of questions that describe power selecting\sharing with fets) or you could use a schottky and reduce the diode drop.

> Is it a good idea to place the two capacitors? Are the values
> reasonable?

You will need more capacitance, how much will depend on the drop. Look at the drop when you turn a relay on on the Vin rail (with a scope) and keep adding capacitance until the drop is higher than at least 4.3V (3.3V plus dropout of the AMS1117). The dropout can be very short, so make sure the probes of the oscilloscope are placed in good locations. In addition make sure the layout has sufficient copper for power rails (like 100mil wide or make sure that there are no high resistance points on the pcb, a 12mil trace at 1" is 33mOhm with 1oz copper).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe your information points to a DC problem or a 3.3V noise problem, but rather an EMI problem from either the coil transient currents or the load switched currents. Of course, you need to follow datasheet guidelines for low ESR caps.

But you haven't identified the root cause of the problem yet.

- Measure the noise on 3.3V with an AC coupled 50 Ohm coax and 50 Ohm terminated DSO when errors are induced.
- If Vdd noise is < 10%, then it may be a radiated and coupled problem elsewhere.
- show photos of entire system , when problems occur and block diagrams of all grounds , loads and power.